# Transmission distance with AM2320 temperature and humidity sensor

Tags: sensor, i2c, temperature, transmission, humidity

I'm about to work with a temperature/Humidity sensor, this sensor has to be wired more than 5m and less than 10 m to my PCB board, I was going to use the SHT3xx sensors, these sensors work with I2C output protocol. I read that I2C has a reach of 2m more or less, so I left behind the SHT3xx option.

I started to consider the DHTXX line of sensors in the datasheet they assure 20 m of transmission distance, furthermore, looking for a DHTXX accurate I found the AM2320, that sensor has I2C output but I'm afraid that the 20 m of distance that (ASONG manufacturer) says in the datasheet, probably not achieve with I2C.

Has anyone worked with the AM2320 and tested the transmission distance?
If I use the I2C of the AM2320, will I get more than 5 m of transmission distance?
thanks.

Comment: I2C is too high impedance for any distance >2 =>5m max and depends on interference , so RS485 differential is better or wireless sensors which is what I use from Banggood

Comment: While I2C is basically meant for on-board communication between ICs and perhaps between boards, but with careful design it can be used for at least 10 meters. If you need proof, video interfaces such as HDMI, DVI, and VGA cables all use I2C protocol for configuration and cables longer than 10m exists.

Comment: There are also transmitter/receiver chips (Bus Extenders, 50 m) for I2C to extend distance.  P82B(something-something).

Comment: RS232 or RS485 is suitable for this. I2c is not suitable for long-range. SPI can be used I think, but needs to be tested.